# migrating from business account to personal

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account

I have a Google business account (with email and all), and I have a personal Google Mail account. Since I don't have the business anymore, I want to get rid of that account.

Currently, I'm using Google mail with the business account, the private account has a forwarding to the business account and ends up there in the Inbox (mails to the actual business account are labeled separately).

Obviously, all my emails, therefore, are in the business account, and I guess I would lose them if I delete that account.
Would there be any easy way to transfer everything from the business account to the private one?
The only other solution I could think of is disabling the forwarding in the private account and forwarding everything I have in the business account manually :/

Answer (score 1):

#### Two Approaches

1. **Gmail → Gmail**
   You can use Gmail to import old and new messages from another Gmail account.
2. **Gmail → IMAP Client → Gmail**
   You can use a third-party IMAP email client to copy messages between the two Gmail accounts.

## 1.  Gmail → Gmail

Source: [Gmail Help: Check emails from other accounts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289)

#### A.  From: Gmail Workspace Account

These instructions assume you are logged into the Google Workspace Gmail Account you are trying to get the email **from**.

1. In Gmail, click [`Settings > See all settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP`](https://mail.google.com#settings/fwdandpop)
2. In the **POP download** section select **Enable POP for all mail** then **Save Changes**.
   [image: Enable POP for all mail]
3. [Optional] If you have [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) enabled, you might need to create and use an app password:

   1. [`Account > Security > How you sign in to Google > 2-Step Verification > App passwords`](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)
   2. Provide an **App name** such as "For TauTau's Personal Gmail" then click **Create**.
      [image: For TauTau's Personal Gmail]
   3. Copy the generated app password to a safe place then click **Done**.
      [image: Generated app password]

#### B.  To: Personal Gmail Account

These instructions assume you are logged into the Personal Gmail Account you are trying to get the email **into**.

1. In Gmail, click [`Settings > See all settings > Accounts and Import`](https://mail.google.com#settings/accounts)
2. In the **Check mail from other accounts** section, click **Add a mail account**.
3. Enter your **Google Workspace email** address and click **Next**.
4. Select **Import emails from my other account (POP3)** then **Next**.
5. Use your Workspace account info to populate the **Add a mail account** dialog with the information that follows then click **Add Account**:

   1. **Username** is your Google Workspace email address
   2. **Password** is the app password created in the previous section **A**.
   3. Check **Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail.**
   4. [Optional] Check **Label incoming messages:** and choose a new or existing label.
   5. [Optional] Check **Leave a copy of retrieved message on the server.** If you leave this unchecked it may be easier to tell if all your messages transferred over.
      [image: Add a mail account]

## 2.  Gmail → IMAP Client → Gmail

### Example using Thunderbird

#### A.  Enable IMAP in both Gmail Accounts

Complete these steps **for both** your Google Workspace and also your Personal Gmail account.

1. In Gmail, click [`Settings > See all settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP`](https://mail.google.com#settings/fwdandpop)
2. In the **IMAP access** section select **Enable IMAP** and **Do not limit the number of messages in an IMAP folder** then **Save Changes**.
   [image: IMAP access]

#### B.  Configure Thunderbird for both accounts

Source: [Thunderbird and Gmail, Configuring your Gmail account](https://%20https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_configuring-your-gmail-account)

Complete these steps **for both** your Google Workspace and also your Personal Gmail account.

1. In Thunderbird select **File > New > Existing Mail Account…**
2. In the Mail Account Setup dialog provide your account information (real name, email address),
3. Thunderbird will automatically configure your Gmail connection.
4. Click Done, sign in with your Google account if prompted.
5. Thunderbird will begin downloading your existing messages.
6. Review [Google's recommended settings for Thunderbird](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892#zippy=%2Cthunderbird) so that your local actions, such as labeling and deleting, correspond to those that Gmail takes and do not cause any conflicts.

#### C.  Move Messages between accounts

Once both accounts are setup you can move or copy messages between them

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the Google service to handle a "business account" like the one referred to in this question is branded as **Google Workspace**.

The OP is right; deleting their *Google Workspace account* will also delete the email messages in this account's Inbox as well as the contacts, files, etc.

The most import keywords that are missing here are **import**, **export**, **transfer**. Another keyword that might be helpful is **Takeout** as it's the name that Google gave to the Google Account feature to export the data.

## As an end-user

1. Using the Google Workspace account, a regular user might go to https://account.google.com.
2. Open the section **Data & Privacy**.
3. Go to the page section **Data from apps and services you use**
   From this section, a regular user might review what Google services are holding user data, access the service settings, help, and other things with one click.

## As a Google Workspace administrator

1. Using the Google Workspace account, a Google Workspace administrator might go to https://admin.google.com.
2. If the menu is collapsed, click the Menu button to expand it.
3. Go to **@ Account > Data Migration** or to **@ Account > Takeout**.
   From these pages, a Google Workspace administrator can learn about the option for Data Migration and getting the domain data out from Google.